# conditional ssl check in nginx.conf

Tags: ssl, nginx, nginx-config

Can we add `ssl` directive inside `if` condition?

I want to achieve something like:

```
if ($host ~ "^localhost") {
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /home/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/ssl/nginx.key;
}
```

If the host is localhost then apply ssl otherwise don't.

Is this possible in `nginx.conf`?

Comment: Can I ask the reason why you need a certificate only for localhost? I don't get why you are doing that. (I fel I can help you better if I know what you really want to do).

Comment: What do you mean by SSL check? These statements configure the server and must be located within a `server` block (or inherited).